# Jquery FileUploader FileList is empty (UI5 Object)

Tags: jquery, sapui5, jquery-file-upload

I have a FileUploader and when I am trying to upload something It is working but When I am using another way The upload don't trigered.

When i debug the FileUploader.js I saw that the problem not in the upload but it is in the FIleList of the Input Type File thath not Fill correctelly.
It's staying with empty value.

My Object is the view is like that:

```
<VBox>
    <u:FileUploader     id                  =   "FilesUploaderFT"
                        name                =   "myFileUploadFT"
                        uploadUrl           =   "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZFT_GW_FILE_MNGMT_SRV/FileMngmtSet"
                        uploadComplete      =   "uploaderUploadComplete"
                        change              =   "uploaderValueChange"
                        typeMissmatch       =   "uploaderTypeMissmatch"
                        style               =   "Emphasized"
                        valueState          =   "{UploadImage>/urlState}"
                        iconOnly            =   "true"
                        icon                =   "sap-icon://add"
                        fileType            =   "png,jpg,jpeg"
                        sendXHR             =   "true"
                        width               =   "150px"
                        visible             =   "{Edit>/EditOn}" 
                        value               =   "{UploadImage>/URL}"
                        class               =   "sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/>

    <Input              value               =   "{UploadImage>/description}"
                        visible             =   "{Edit>/EditOn}"
                        valueState          =   "{UploadImage>/descriptionSate}" 
                        width               =   "150px"
                        class               =   "sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/>
</VBox>
```

When I debug on change event I have no value on the fileList

```
uploaderValueChange: function (evt){
    console.log(evt);
}
```

My result is like that:
[image]

I'm using SAPUI5 1.38 in production.

Comment: I tried it with SAPUI5 version 1.38.5 with your exact code. I debugged oEvent and I got the file back just fine. Are you sure you're not using an older version?

Comment: Could you maybe include your entire view with namespaces?

Comment: I told you that in the first time i get the file but after navigation from app to other app i have problem on it